# Populating Combox with first entry

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, frameworks, combobox

I am using the following technique for populating a combobox in winforms:

```
var customer = (new Customer[] { new Customer { CustomerID = -1, CustomerRef = "[Please Select]" } }).Concat(
    from c in ctx.Customers
    orderby c.CustomerRef ascending
    select c).ToList();

cboCustomerRef.DataSource = customer;
cboCustomerRef.ValueMember = "CustomerID";
cboCustomerRef.DisplayMember = "CustomerRef";
```

Would it be possible to achieve the same result, but with only selecting the two relevant columns (CustomerID and CustomerRef) from customer rather than all columns.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you...

Comment: `Anonymous type` with `new {....}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var customers = 
    from c in ctx.Customers
    orderby c.CustomerRef ascending
    select new { CustomerId = c.CustomerID, CustomerRef = c.CustomerRef }).ToList();

customers.Insert(0, new { CustomerID = -1, CustomerRef = "[Please Select]"});

cboCustomerRef.DataSource = customers;
cboCustomerRef.ValueMember = "CustomerID";
cboCustomerRef.DisplayMember = "CustomerRef";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use DropDown event to retrieve you data and make 
combobox

> Customers.Text=[Please Select]

by default.